# pointer to 3d array

Tags: c#, unsafe, intptr

i have a 3D array and i want to get `IntPtr` to point on it so here what i did ..can anyone tell me if it's right or not...

```
fixed (Int16* mypointer = &myvolume[0, 0, 0])
{
     //then i cast mypointer as IntPtr
}
```

notice that myvolume is of dimensions 200 x 100 x 100

Comment: Have you tried it to see if it works?

Comment: You do understand that the IntPtr won't be valid after you exit the `fixed` block, right?

Comment: yes i know that's why in inserted all my code inside the Fixed block, thanks for your concern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that what you really want is an *unsafe* pointer?  Using pointers like this is very very rare in C# land.

Eric Lippert recently wrote about a [simple class that offers some of the behavior of pointers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/10/references-and-pointers-part-two.aspx), without resorting to unsafe code.  You might consider extending it to work with your multidimensional arrays.

Comment: THanks Chris ,actually i'm using some vtk algorithms that requires a pointer to my volume that's why i'm using pointers, i'll check this article, Thanks for your effort

Comment: It's not as rare as you'd think. Pointer arithmetic is by far the fastest way to iterate over arrays like this and you'll find a lot of this kind of code in performance critical apps.

Comment: @MattDavey I agree there are places for it, and have used it myself for image manipulation routines.  The danger is that programmers new to "high performance" computing in C# will jump right to pointers without trying/profiling the standard C# solutions.

Comment: actually i used it before with another SDKs but i was troubleshooting a problem so i wanted to make sure if i use it appropriately :)